# Zommdata example running error

Tags: filter, visualization

I have created a visualization in zoomdata. It is connecting with our server properly. the sample has been taken from this url: 
https://github.com/Zoomdata/SDK20-ApplicationFW-samples/blob/master/simpleSamples/changeColorAndFilter.html

The sample runs properly. **but when I connect with our live server the button "change filter" doesn't work.** Change color button works. It shows following error :

```
Calling deprecated method filters.add;
  zoomdata-client.js:65725:12
Object { instance: Object, schema: Object, propertyPath: "instance", errors: Array[1], throwError: undefined, disableFormat: false }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

However I changed my code little bit and it works fine.

Previous method:

window.viz.filters.add(filterSet[filterNum]);

Changed Method:

window.viz.filters.changeFilters(filterSet[filterNum]);